# Python generate xml with variable number of elements using cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I am writing a Python 3.x script that collects an unknown number of variables and needs to write them as sub elements in an XML file.
c
The problem is that every document I have seen that uses cElementTree needs to declare an element using a variable like so...

```
randomData =  etree.Element("randomData")
```

Since there is no way of knowing how many of these are needed beforehand it would be very helpful if elements could be created without the need for hardcoding the xml element structure.

Comment: do you absolutely need it to be XML? If you just want to save some variables in a file for later reading, there are many ways to do this in python and all of them are (In my biased opinion) better than XML.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The file needs to be read by another program which implements its own parser and script language and only supports xml. Otherwise I would have left xml for something else.

Comment: Can you give us an example in and output?

Comment: The input that the xml needs to be generated from is a bunch of nested dictionary's and lists. something like {"Root":{"category":{"subcategory":{"someObject":{"SomeObjectAttribute":["randomStuff", "moreRandomStuff"]}}}}}. And the output would be making all the categorys as sub elements with the same relation to each-other as what the dictionary has with the list being the data to store in the element.

Comment: does https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dicttoxml/1.5.4 solve your problem?

Comment: Just tried it out and it seems to work. +1 to you sir. I would like to mark the answer but I don't see the option in the comments here.

Comment: It should be noted for others reading this that dicttoxml is under the GLPv2 license and may not be compatible with non-gpl. My project is under MIT and will need to research this a bit before using.